# How would I write a trigger to reorder a sequence number?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I have a simple table in Oracle with three columns:

```
ID    NCHAR(10)
NAME  NCHAR(50)
SEQ   NUMBER
```

The `SEQ` field is 0 based and there to allow the user to drag the records and reorder the list (using jQuery sortable). I'm trying to figure out how to change all of the sequence numbers so they end up in the correct order in the database.

I started to create a trigger before update to change all of the `SEQ` numbers based on the `:OLD` and `:NEW` values, but stopped when I realized that this would cause an infinite loop when the trigger would just keep running since I am updating a bunch of records.

Is there a way I can get a trigger to carry out this behavior or should I write it manually into the code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: why store the new sequences at all?  After all, user could change it constantly.  Why not just change the query's order by (server side) or cache the data sans order by and sort in cache (client side)?

Comment: This is going in kind of a meta table, that holds information that was previously hard-coded in the application.  I'm making an administration page now so that the admin can change the order in which things are displayed.  There's no field that logically orders the records, and we want something different than just alphabetical.  They also won't be sorted client-side since they appear pretty static to regular users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to scrap the idea of using a consecutive sequence and instead update moved record to be the average of the previous and next value at the given location.

For example, say you have this list:

```
ID   NAME    SEQ
1111 Fred    10
2222 Bob     20
3333 Ted     30
```

To move "Ted" to the second space in the list, you'd set the sequence to 15 (20+10/2). If you later move someone between "Fred" and "Ted", they get a seq of 12.5. If you really felt the need, you could have an `after update` trigger on the whole table (rather than for each row) that set the SEQ to evenly spaced values.

Comment: Now that I think about it I really like this one.  Only one update each time and no loops. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Reordering the sequence through a trigger will be really difficult, especially if `SEQ` is UNIQUE and policed by a non-deferrable constraint. Your update would activate the trigger, which would in turn modify other rows, each update in turn would activate said trigger...

Fortunately this infinite recursion would be really hard to code in Oracle since [you can't modify/query the base table in a trigger](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/ASKTOM.download_file?p_file=6551198119097816936).

In a case like this, I would advise using a procedural approach. In PLSQL for example:

```
PROCEDURE update_sequence(p_id NUMBER, 
                          p_new_seq NUMBER) IS
   l_old_seq NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT seq INTO l_old_seq FROM my_table WHERE ID = p_id;
   UPDATE my_table
      SET seq = CASE WHEN ID = p_id 
                        THEN p_new_seq 
                        ELSE seq + sign(l_old_seq - p_new_seq) 
                END
    WHERE seq BETWEEN least(l_old_seq, p_new_seq) 
                  AND greatest(l_old_seq, p_new_seq);
END;
```

This will place row `p_id` at sequence `p_new_seq` and all rows between the new position and the old will have their sequence either increased or decreased by 1.

Comment: Thanks!  I actually ended up doing this with pretty much the exact same code, only sent from my application rather then a procedure.  I guess it would be a better practice to use a procedure.

Answer (score 0):

use a linked list approach.

point a record to the record right in front of it in the order.  then you minimize updates.

Comment: I'm familiar with a linked list, but I'm not sure I understand completely. Would I just update the record before or after (depending on the order) recursively using the trigger until I am out of records?

Comment: you will not be able to do this in the same table on a trigger.  the update will need to be external, or you will need to move the link to another table if you want to trigger it. (mutation)

Comment: Yeah I'm still lost.  I think I'll end up doing it manually from my application